# Want to add my custom prepare query but add_filter doesn't run

Tags: wp-user-query

I want to manipulate the order of `WP_User_Query()`. I want the user to come out ordered by a custom meta field and by ascending order.

I have the code correctly working tested it on `users.php` but since this is not a good place to put it I wanted to run `add_filter( 'prepare_query', 'my_prepare_query');`

The call in the theme ('include' doesn't exist):

```
$count_args = array(
    'include' => $include,
    'number' => 999999,
    'fields' => 'ID',
    'orderby' => 'include',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$user_count_query = new WP_User_Query( $count_args );
```

I just simply added another `elseif` to `prepare_query` on line 433 of `user.php`:

```
elseif ( 'include' == $qv[ 'orderby' ] ) {

    $this->query_from .= " INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_usermeta.user_id = $wpdb->users.ID";
    $this->query_where .= " AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'my_userpoints'";
    $orderby = "wp_usermeta.meta_value";
}
```

Now why is the `add_filter` not overwriting the `user.php` function? Is it not possible to overwrite core functions?

Comment: Can you link to where `prepare_query` is in the core code? (I'm not sure it exists).

Comment: its in wp-includes... 
Maybe I dont understand your question

Comment: @DavidRosendo ... *where* is `wp-includes`? The only `prepare_query` I see is a [**method** of the `WP_User_Search` class](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/user.php#L315), not a filter.

Comment: I think you want the `pre_user_query` action to modify user query SQL directly.

Answer (score 1):

The [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) allows `meta_query` searches exactly like the other `WP_*_Query` classes. Example here:

```
global $wpdb;
$author_search = new WP_User_Query( array(
    'role'       => 'subscriber', 
    'fields'     => 'all_with_meta',
    // if it's a digit/int/float, use 'meta_value_num'
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    // you could try -1 as well.
    'nuber'      => 99999999,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key'     => 'my_userpoints',
        // only needed if you got a specific value you search for
        // 'value'   => '',
        // only needed if you got a specific value you search for
        // and want to compare against it. For e.g. '>', '<', etc. See Codex.
        // 'compare' => '',
        'type'    => 'CHAR', // this is the default, use INT if you got an int/float value
    ),
) );
$author_list   = $author_search->get_results();
$author_count  = $wpdb->num_rows;
```